# Couldn't access object in function

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a `for` loop, the `i` is my loop counter.

```
console.log($(f_images[i].DOM));

$(f_images[i].DOM).hover(function() {
    console.log($(f_images[i].DOM));
}, function() {});
```

Console showed me:

```
[object Object]
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DOM' of undefined".
```

Same thing happened if I replace `$(f_images[i].DOM)` with whatever related to `f_images`.

Why can't I access the object array itself in the hover function?

Comment: Is this in a loop? Is `i` your loop counter?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it's in a for loop.

Comment: Impossible to tell why that happens other than the `DOM` property is missing from some (or all) of your `f_images` elements.

Comment: Read that message carefully... It's not that `DOM` is undefined on the objects, it's that `f_images[i]` is returning `undefined`, which raises an exception when you try to access a property of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have this problem: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

By the time your hover function runs, `i` is the last value that would end the loop, the first index out of range.

Use a closure to close over `i` in your loop as described in that answer and it should work as you expect.

```
for (var i = 0; i < f_images.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    $(f_images[i].DOM).hover(function(){
      console.log($(f_images[i].DOM));
    }, function(){

    });
  }(i));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

replace

```
$(f_images[i].DOM)
```

with:

```
$('f_images' + [i] + '.DOM')
```

Comment: `$('f_images' + [i] + '.DOM')` makes no sense here. A jQuery selector cannot be used to read local variables like what `f_images` seems to be.